# Port Forwarding through my home modem

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, port, portforwarding

I am trying to do port forwarding by using my JioFi modem .
After setting up all configurations , I am getting port closed when I use online website to check the port status.
I am not able to find out the problem . I have tried disabling the firewall too .
Below is detailed steps I did to port forward (I am mentioning it because their may be few things I may have missed while setting up things ...)..
(My System in Ubuntu 14.04) ..
1) Logged in to router home page . (My JioFi's web UI)
2)Went to port forwarding menu and set the Local port and WAN port as 12345 ans saved the settings .
3)Started a simple server at 12345 .
4) Used http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ website to check the port but it showed port closed ...

Please help . A detailed stepwise answer would be really helpful .
I used following website to learn about port forwarding :- https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/

Answer (score 1):

What is the wan IP your router get? If the wan IP is in private range https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network, port forwarding at the router will not help because port forwarding has to be done at ISP as first NAT happens there. If your router has public wan IP then port forwarding should work. In the case of private IP use third party tunneling service like ngrok to access your site publicly

Comment: yes my wan IP is in private range (it starts with 10.*.*.*)                      
thanks for the advice about ngork . I find ngork really interesting but I am still having few troubles . 
I would list them , please help me through it (I am really new to ngork so please guide me through the solution .)

Comment: I am listing the steps I have done after downloading and unzipping ngork :-  
1) I ran ngork for http server by command "./ngork http 80" . A web UI at http://localhost:4040 started showing results . But when I clicked on the link of main page a "502 Bad Gateway" error came (I think it is because no http server is running on port 80 . I guess?).

Comment: 2) So now I tried to run my tcp server code written in python which is listening on port 12345 . I started ngork by command "./ngork tcp 12345" , then I ran my python code for server , a web UI was again displayed successfully . But now when I again check whether port 12345 is open or not from website http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ , it again displays port closed !!

Comment: it will be really  helpful if you can tell me how exactly I can make my system a chat server where other clients (in different network) can send connection request and then chat . I can see that I will be needing port forwarding for the purpose or "ngork" , you have suggested . If I use ngork then please tell me how exactly should i do it and how should i test whether it worked (only way i know is through above mentioned website)? Also it will be really helpful , if you can tell me what will be the IP address where my clients needs to send connection request to server (i.e. my local system ) .

Comment: Thanks for your help